# Evaluate the integral $\int \frac{x}{a+bx^3}\ dx$

Tags: integration

How do I solve integral at this form
$\displaystyle\int \frac{x}{a+bx^3}\ dx$ ?

Comment: Partial fractions, you always have at least one real root so you can factor the denominator.  It is certainly messy.

Comment: Making a substitution $u=\sqrt[3]{a/b\,}\,x$ and using partial fractions looks like it should work since, as @lulu said, you can factor the denominator to be a linear polynomial times a quadratic polynomial.

Answer (score 5):

partial fraction : in general form ,write it like below 
  and find  A,B,C 
$$\frac{x}{a+bx^3}= \\ \frac{x}{(\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}x)((\sqrt[3]{a})^2+(\sqrt[3]{b}x)^2-(\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{b}x))}=\\ \space \\ \frac{A}{(\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}x)}+\frac{Bx+C}{((\sqrt[3]{a})^2+(\sqrt[3]{b}x)^2-(\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{b}x))} $$ then you will have logarithm part  + log or arctan part (depends on a,b)

Answer (score 3):

$$
a+bx^3 = (\sqrt[3]a +x\sqrt[3]b)(\sqrt[3]a^2 - x\sqrt[3]a\sqrt[3]b + x^2\sqrt[3]b^2)
$$

So use partial fractions:
$$
\frac x {a+bx^3} = \frac C {\sqrt[3]a +x\sqrt[3]b} + \frac {Dx+E} {\sqrt[3]a^2 - x\sqrt[3]a\sqrt[3]b + x^2\sqrt[3]b^2}
$$